# too many cookies

Tags: ellipsis, quantifiers

Can one use

a. Too many cookies are bad for you.

instead of

b. Having too many cookies is bad for you.

=================

Can one use

c. Many cookies are bad for you.

instead of

d. Having many cookies is bad for you.

=====================

Can one use 'is' instead of 'are' in (a) and (c)?

One meaning of (c) is: There are many cookies that are bad for you. (Some aren't bad, but many are.)

I am not sure that (c) can be used instead of (d) though.

Many thanks.

Comment: A and B can mean different things, and C and D definitely mean different things.

Answer (score 1):

> b) Having too many cookies is bad for you.

This sentence is not clear: [have](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/have) could mean own (meaning 1 in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/have)) or consume (meaning 4.2).

> a) Too many cookies are bad for you.

Although this doesn't state what you are doing with the cookies, this is actually clearer and more natural: the listener will assume that you are referring to **eating** too many cookies.

> c) Many cookies are bad for you.

In my opinion, this can only have the meaning that you suggested: some (but not all) types of cookie are bad for you.

> d) Having many cookies is bad for you.

This sentence suffers from the confusion over owning and consuming: also, we don't tend to use **many** in his context: it is too formal, and it carries overtones of *a large proportion of those in a group* as in sentence c. **a lot of** would work better. Sentence d would therefore be better written as

> eating a lot of cookies is bad for you.

Comment: Well, while *logically* I agree that sentence is ambiguous, no one will really think that simple *possession* of cookies can cause problems.  It's usually the *eating* that leads to misery and regret, in any language.

Comment: @Andrew depends where you store them :-) Seriously, I agree that **having** is understandable, but in my opinion it is not natural, and I am trying to explain why. I don't say it's wrong: it simply say that it's not clear.

Comment: I would argue that when referring to eating too many cookies you have to use singular, not plural: "too many cookies *is* bad for you", not "are". "Too many cookies are bad for you" is more like "there are kinds of cookies that are bad for you, and there's too many of them" to me.